# how to select all rigid bodies in my scene?

Tags: rigidbody

I need to bake all rigid bodies to keyframes.

How can i select all of my objects with rigid body?

I tried searching for such a function but i didn't find any.

Comment: Select one RB, then shift-g select grouped -> collection -> rigidbodyworld .

Comment: Great Nathan, thank you!!!! if you wanna write an answer -> you will get 1 upvote and a check

Comment: Ehh, it's too short and I don't want/need to expand :)  Nor do I need points.  Feel free though!

Comment: yeah, i will add it, because i forgot this in 2 weeks and i will search again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Nathan,

1. select one rigid body object
2. Press <kbd>SHIFT-G</kbd>
3. Choose collection

If this object is only in one collection, you are done.

if it has more collections, you can choose the collection:

[image]

Comment: i was thinking of writing a script but then i tried this which is definitely the way to go :D

Comment: that's what i thought would be necessary too...fortunately Nathan know the shortcut and fortunately Blender implemented it ;)